# Control detectChange strategy for different variables in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am not expert at Angular 4 and I have been building an app with Angular 4. So, I am trying to understand change detection functionalities due to it is unclear to me. At the moment, I use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in `ngAfterViewInit` method. Lets say I have a sample UI component which is it like:

```
<div>{{state}}</div>
```

and I have two variables in the class which are `state` and `stateUpdater`. My stateUpdater:

```
this.state = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    this.stateUpdater = 0;
    if (this.stateUpdater % 8 === 0) {
      this.state = this.stateUpdater;
    }
    this.stateUpdater++;
}, 100);
```

So, for this case, `stateUpdater` would be updated every 100 ms and `state` would be updated every 800 ms. My question is that is 'detectChanges' function will be called every 100 ms to update UI? Otherwise, will be called every 800 ms?

If it is going to be called every 100 ms, how can I prevent this behavior? Because this is completely inefficient for UI perspective.

I will appreciate any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: What `detectChanges` are you talking about? What `800ms` are you talking about? In the code I see, it will be updated every 100ms.

Comment: Edited the question to fix some errors. The point of OP is whether or not change triggered by watchers.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef .  Be careful, state variable won't be updated every 100 ms. So, I do not need to update UI every 100 ms. I do not know how can I explain more clearly.

Comment: You should not need to do *anything* to handle UI changes in your application other than to bind the values. Angular's automatic change detection will handle the rest. Trying to *also* update the state yourself using timer/interval functionality will cause you problems and potential race conditions.

Comment: You can `detach` the change detector and call `detectChange()` manually whenever you want to detect change on your component.

Comment: @DeborahK not sure what you mean. If I do not call detectChanges method, UI cannot be updated. This is just an example to understand how Angular works. Otherwise, I am not doing anything similar in my application.  Because, I am going to build very large application and testing the performance. However, this detectChanges functions consume too much allocated memory. That's why, I need to control it.

Comment: As I said, it was just a sample. I want to fire detectChanges method only if variables that effects UI are changed. I believe private variables should not trigger this detectChanges method because there is no impact on UI.

Comment: As for detach method, yes I can disable with this. I thought about it, but this will cause complexity in the codes. Because, I need disable and enable every change. I am trying to improve performance, but this would make it worst.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the issue/question ... but you should not need to do anything to update your UI based on changes to your property values.

RE:

> If I do not call detectChanges method, UI cannot be updated.

NO, this is not how Angular works. *Many* Angular developers (myself included) have done Angular applications that updated their UI without ever using `detectChanges`.

Here is an example using a service ... but you don't have to use a service:

https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

**Simple component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({ 
 template: ` 
  <div> 
    <h2>Data from A: {{ data }} </h2> 
    <input [(ngModel)] = data /> 
    <br><br> 
    <a [routerLink]="['/b']">Go to B</a> 
  </div> 
  `, 
}) 
export class A {

  get data():string { 
    return this.dataService.serviceData; 
  } 
  set data(value: string) { 
    this.dataService.serviceData = value; 
  } 

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { } 
}
```

NOTE: The template is included as part of this component for easier cutting and pasting. In a "real" application this template would be a separate file.

Here is a plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

I used a similar technique to update the UI on the right here every time the user selected a value on the left:

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and thank you so much for preparing a plunker to represent how Angular handle automatic change detection. However, I should have explained my situation better in my question. I have to use ChangeDetector operations in the app in order to get better performance. As I mentioned above, I am building a very large application and I have to be very careful about performance. So, I have to consider every single case when I build the app. Please read this article: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html .

Comment: At that article, you would understand me why I need to use changeDetection. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle is applicable to entire component or directive.

It is zoned `setInterval` that triggers change detection, not changed `stateUpdater` value.

If some change detection is undesirable in some piece of code, it can locally disabled by evaluating the code outsize current zone with [`runOutsideAngular`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#runOutsideAngular). `run` can re-enable it locally:

```
ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    if (this.stateUpdater % 8 === 0) {
      ngZone.run(() => {
        // yes! change detection
        this.state = this.stateUpdater;
      });
    }
    // no change detection
    this.stateUpdater++;
  }, 100);
});
```

Alternatively, change detection can be triggered manually when needed:

```
zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    if (this.stateUpdater % 8 === 0) {
      // yes! change detection
      this.state = this.stateUpdater;
      changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
    // no change detection
    this.stateUpdater++;
  }, 100);
});
```

Change detection can be temporarily disabled with [`detach`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detach) and enabled with `reattach`. Their effects aren't local, the entire component is affected:

```
  setInterval(() => {
    if (this.stateUpdater % 8 === 0) {
      changeDetectorRef.reattach();
      // yes! change detection
      this.state = this.stateUpdater;
    } else {
      // no change detection
      changeDetectorRef.detach();
      this.stateUpdater++;
    }
  }, 100);
```

Change detection is *relatively* low-cost operation, this is the reason why it exists. If no changes were detected in properties that were bound to view, the view won't be updated.

Since change detection is the essential part of the framework, it's supposed to be used as is in most cases, while fine-grained control over it defies the purpose of using the framework and can be considered premature optimization, unless proven otherwise.

In order for change detection cycles that don't result in view changes to not cause significant impact on performance, view bindings shouldn't be costly.

Comment: This is a very nice explanation. It sounds pretty good approach to go with it, but I do have some concerns that detaching/attaching might cause a worse performance. Actually, let me do a quick test and see how is it gonna be. I will inform you. Thank you.